# qt creator gives "no target specified" with cmake file

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

It builds fine from console Cmake, but when I try to open the project and build it from Qt Creator I see `no targets specified`.

Qt Creator version 3.1.1

CMake file

```
project(wordnetTest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
        set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
        message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/include/ ./wordnet-blast-master)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

find_library(LIBWN WN HINTS "/usr/local/WordNet-3.0/lib")
if(NOT LIBWN)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Library `WN` not found")
endif()

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBWN})
```

Comment: Isn't the `no target specified` message from make not cmake ?

Comment: any update for you question?

Comment: @Ehsan unfortunately no, I switched to QMake

Comment: I could solve my case today, it may can help you too

Comment: I could solve my case today, it may can help you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481685/how-open-qt-creator-project-itk-snap-using-cmake